# Is that a tag list or something else?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I am new to NLP and NLTK, and I want to find ambiguous words, meaning words with at least `n` different tags. I have this method, but the output is more than confusing.

Code:

```
def MostAmbiguousWords(words, n):
# wordsUniqeTags holds a list of uniqe tags that have been observed for a given word
wordsUniqeTags = {}
for (w,t) in words:
    if wordsUniqeTags.has_key(w):
        wordsUniqeTags[w] = wordsUniqeTags[w] | set(t)
    else:
        wordsUniqeTags[w] = set([t])
# Starting to count
res = []
for w in wordsUniqeTags:
    if len(wordsUniqeTags[w]) >= n:
        res.append((w, wordsUniqeTags[w]))

return res
MostAmbiguousWords(brown.tagged_words(), 13)
```

Output:

```
[("what's", set(['C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'H', 'WDT+BEZ', '-', 'N', 'T', 'W', 'V', 'Z', '+'])),
("who's", set(['C', 'B', 'E', 'WPS+BEZ', 'H', '+', '-', 'N', 'P', 'S', 'W', 'V', 'Z'])),
("that's", set(['C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'H', '+', '-', 'N', 'DT+BEZ', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'V', 'Z'])),
('that', set(['C', 'D', 'I', 'H', '-', 'L', 'O', 'N', 'Q', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'CS']))]
```

Now I have no idea what `B`,`C`,`Q`, ect. could represent. So, my questions:

- What are these?
- What do they mean? (In case they are tags)
- I think they are not tags, because `who` and `whats` don't have the `WH` tag indicating "wh question words".

I'll be happy if someone could post a link that includes a mapping of all possible tags and their meaning.

Comment: How are you adding tags to words? It looks like you're truncating or splitting them somehow. Like maybe instead of adding "WH", you added "W" and "H"?

Comment: I don't do that, I use the [brown corpus](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html) that is available for download [here](http://nltk.org/data.html). It is widely used among people that work on NLP. (At least it seems to me that many are using it)

Comment: Hm. I wonder if you're truncating the tags in a way I'm not seeing? What happens if you `print t` on each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo.  In this line:

```
wordsUniqeTags[w] = wordsUniqeTags[w] | set(t)
```

you should have `set([t])` (not `set(t)`), like you do in the `else` case.

This explains the behavior you're seeing because `t` is a string and `set(t)` is making a set out of each character in the string.  What you want is `set([t])` which makes a set that has `t` as its element.

```
>>> t = 'WHQ'
>>> set(t)
set(['Q', 'H', 'W'])    # bad
>>> set([t])
set(['WHQ'])            # good
```

By the way, you can correct the problem *and* simplify things by just changing that line to:

```
wordsUniqeTags[w].add(t)
```

But, really, you should make use of the `setdefault` method on `dict` and list comprehension syntax to improve the method overall.  So try this instead:

```
def most_ambiguous_words(words, n):
  # wordsUniqeTags holds a list of uniqe tags that have been observed for a given word
  wordsUniqeTags = {}
  for (w,t) in words:
    wordsUniqeTags.setdefault(w, set()).add(t)
  # Starting to count
  return [(word,tags) for word,tags in wordsUniqeTags.iteritems() if len(tags) >= n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting your POS tags into single characters in this line:

```
    wordsUniqeTags[w] = wordsUniqeTags[w] | set(t)
```

`set('AT')` results in `set(['A', 'T'])`.

Answer (score 0):

How about making use of the Counter and defaultdict functionality in the collections module?

```
from collection import defaultdict, Counter

def most_ambiguous_words(words, n):
    counts = defaultdict(Counter)
    for (word,tag) in words:
        counts[word][tag] += 1
    return [(w, counts[w].keys()) for w in counts if len(counts[word]) > n]
```